# Django template {% trans %} pluralization

Tags: django, django-templates

According to [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag) in the Django docs I should use `{% blocktrans %}` for cases where I need to translate pluralizations. However, with an example like the following, isn't there something more convenient I can do?

```
{% blocktrans count video.views.count as views %}
The video has been viewed <span>{{ views }}</span> time
{% plural %}
The video has been viewed <span>{{ views }}</span> times
{% endblocktrans %}
```

I tried to do the following:

```
{% blocktrans %}time{% plural %}times{% endblocktrans %}
```

But it threw `TemplateSyntaxError: 'blocktrans' doesn't allow other block tags (seen u'plural') inside it`

Comment: This makes it very hard for translators, as you are forcing an ordering of words; what if the translation requires to have the plural form in front of the `{{ views }}`? The verbose expression really is the way to go.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You forgot the `count variable as variable_name` in the blocktrans tag

The value of that variable will be used to detect if it's plural or not.

```
{% blocktrans count variable as variable_name %}
    time
    {% plural %}
    {{ variable_name }} times
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Ah now I see :) I still feel like there should be a more convenient way than this though:

{% trans "The video has been viewed" %} <span>{{ video.views.count }}</span>
{% blocktrans count video.views.count as views %}time{% plural %}times{% endblocktrans %}

Comment: Link to docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#std:templatetag-blocktrans

Answer (score -4):

You can use:

```
{% blocktrans with video.views.count|pluralize as foo  and  video.views.count as views %}
The video has been viewed <span>{{ views }}</span> time{{ foo }}
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: ...that's defeating the use of blocktrans. It's creating more word-puzzles instead. Better go for the `{% plural %}` solution.